# How to send a push notification to all users using firebase admin sdk?

Tags: python, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have an Android app to which I send push notifications via firebase. Now I  am making a Django app that will run on my server. I wanted to send the notification to my app using that django app. I started testing the firebase admin SDK for python. I was learning from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message). I implemented the example code given by the documentation which you can see [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/f2dd24ea6b3c471e4b3146b6d6bb7dc993fcb11d/snippets/messaging/cloud_messaging.py#L24-L40) and it works on the test android app. The problem is that I need the registration tokens of the devices to send a notification which I have not collected. Or I can send a notification to a topic but the problem is that the app users have not subscribed to topics. I previously used firebase console to send the notifications. I used this option while sending notifications:
[image: firebase conole]
Using this option, I sent the notification to all the users of my app. How can I do this with the admin sdk? I want to send notification to all the users of the app. I also tried py-fcm to do this but could not find success. It has the same problem. (If the problem can not be solved using the admin sdk, tell some other library or method to use)

Answer (score 0):

you can not send to all devices in your Firebase panel.
you should use "**Topic**" or "**Group**" for sending to multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do the condition.

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const message = {
  notification: {
    title: 'EPA fuel economy stats for new Mazda6',
    body: 'New turbo charged 2.5L engine does 23/31/36 mpg.',
  },
  condition: `!('your-non-subscribed-news' in topics)`,
};
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log('Message sent successfully:', resp);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Failed to send the message:', err);
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "not" operation by excluding a non-existing topic.

```
!('TopicA' in topics)
```

With this expression, any app instances that are not subscribed to TopicA, including app instances that are not subscribed to any topic, receive the message. If you make sure that none of your users subscribe to "TopicA", you are essentially sending the message to all of your users.

Comment: This is not clear, you didn't provide sufficient information and how the problem is going to be fixed.